# React npx create-react-app ошибка

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Когда я в cmd делаю так: npx create-react-app .
То выводит вот такую ошибку
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\ALIF'
command not found: create-react-app

Как мне создать react app когда мой user такой (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community).
Есть ли какой-нибудь способ для создании react-та с такой ошибкой.

Comment: Установлен ли у Вас Node js? Писали ли вы ранее на чистом JS?

Comment: @Locker да я знаю js и node js установлен. Даже проверил версию node -v. Я думаю не в этом проблема проблама в учётном записе. Когда я меняю учётную запись. Там всё нормально но я хочу чтобы тут работало потому что все данные тут. Скажите как устронить ппоблему?

Comment: Если на этой учетной записи не установлен Node js ничего не получится. Попробуйте написать ```npm  -v``` или ```npx -v```

Comment: @Locker я не проблвал две эти комманды но я сделал так node -v // вывод 14.**.**

Comment: Попробуйте. И отправьте  сюда версию

Comment: ```npx create-react-app nameProject```

Comment: @Locker да я сделал так но выводит ошибку.

Comment: У вас выводит ошибку при npm -v?

Comment: @Locker я отправлю версию завтра я сейчас еду домой я был на занятиях. Если вы завтра будете тут и поможете с этой проблемой я буду вам признателен)

Comment: @Locker нет не выводит ошибку. Оба версии 6.14.13.

Comment: @Greg-- помогите мне с этой ошибкой! Если знаете в чём проблема или понимаете react.

Comment: Дополните, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос скринами с ошибками. Это поможет решить ваш вопрос